# Is there a plugin for compiz that uses a certain window as a desktop background?

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, window-manager, compiz

I want to have a specific window, let's say, a Banshee player window, to be displayed as a background on my desktop. Is it possible to do with compiz on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that the xscreensavers can be set as "wallpaper" with the `-root` switch, i.e. telling them to run in the root window, e.g.

[image]

If you use xgl you can try [xwinwrap](http://swik.net/xwinwrap), too.